# new web app on 1 of 2 wfe servers

Tags: web-application

I have two WFE servers. By default the CA web app gets installed to only one WFE. Is it possible to create a new web app that only gets installed to one WFE?

If not, does it make sense to create the web app as normal, it gets created on both WFE servers, and then we delete it in IIS on the second WFE. Or will that likely cause problems?

The reason for the question is that a group needs their own web app, but they don't need HA like our other users. If we can deploy their stuff on just one WFE then we can cut down on web part licensing costs. I know an alternative would be to put them in their own SharePoint farm, but we'd like to avoid that.

Comment: FYI, I have to say, that I test deleting the IIS site on a server, so I don't know if there is collateral damage, but it still works ... I did not test that much, but site was responding ... (care about dns and AAM).